# Finding the sum of products.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Consider the following two sets of consecutive integers $\{10,11,...19,20\}$ and $\{21,22,...29,30\}$. Each element of the first set is multiplied,in turn, by each element in the second set. Find the sum of all these products.

So basically I have to do the following:

$10 \times 21$

$11 \times 22$

and so on, then i have to add their products. My teacher likes to give questions that involve tricks, but i'm not really seeing the trick here.

Obviously, I can do this with a calculator but I'm trying to look for another way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: You forgot $10\times 22$, $10\times 23$, and so on.

Comment: Show that The sum is equal to $(10+11+\cdots+20)(21+22+\cdots+30)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, your teacher is cute!

$$10(21 + \ldots + 30) + 11(21 + \ldots + 30) + \ldots + 20(21 + \ldots  + 30) =
(10 + 11 + \ldots + 20)(21 + \ldots + 30)$$

If $N = 10 + 11 + \ldots + 20$ then

$$\begin{align}
2N &= (10 + 11 + \ldots + 20) + (20 + 19 + \ldots + 10)\\
&= [(10 + 20) + (11 + 19) + \ldots + (20 + 1)]\\
&= [30 + 30 + 30 + \ldots + 30] \\&= 11\times30 \\&= 330
\end{align}$$

So $N = 165$.

If $M = 21 + 22 + \ldots + 30$ then

$$\begin{align}
2M &= (21 + 22 + \ldots + 30) + (30 + 29 + 28 + \ldots + 21)\\
&= [(21 + 30) + (22 + 29) + \ldots + (30 + 21)]\\
&= [51 + 51 + 51 + \ldots + 51] \\&= 10\times51 \\&= 510
\end{align}$$

So $M = 255$.

So the answer is $165\times255=42075$

---

Useful fact for the future:

$$1 + 2 + \ldots + n = N$$

$$\begin{align}
2N &= (1 + n) + (2 + (n -1)) + \ldots + (n + 1)\\
&= (1 + n) + (1 + n) + \ldots + (1 + n) \\&= n(n + 1)
\end{align}$$

So $N = \dfrac{n(n + 1)}2$.

You will get a *lot* of millage out of that in the future!

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Try it with sets $\{2,3\}$ and $\{5,6,7\}$. You get

$$\underbrace{2\cdot5+2\cdot6+2\cdot7}+\underbrace{3\cdot5+3\cdot6+3\cdot7}\;.$$

Can you factor that to write it as a product of two sums?

Once you manage that, try to generalize the idea to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{i=10}^{20} i\right)\left(\sum_{i=21}^{30} i\right) &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^{20} i - \sum_{j=1}^9 j \right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{30} i - \sum_{j=1}^{20} j \right)\\
&= \left(\frac{20(21)}{2}-\frac{9(10)}2\right)\left(\frac{30(31)}2-\frac{20(21)}2 \right)\\
&= \frac14(20\cdot21-9\cdot10)(30\cdot31-20\cdot21)\\
&= 25(2\cdot 21 - 9)(3\cdot 31-2\cdot21)\\
&= 25\cdot33\cdot51\\
&= 42075.
\end{align}

Comment: I don't think the OP is aware that sum{1 ..... n} = n(n+1)/2.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misunderstood the wording in the exercise slightly. What they want you to compute is $(10\cdot21 + 10 \cdot 22 + ... + 10 \cdot30) + (11 \cdot 21 + 11 \cdot 22 + ... + 11 \cdot 30) + ...$ and so on. If you look at each of these parantheses, you can see that they have a common factor. Extracting the common factors from the parantheses you only need to compute a simple sum to solve your problem.